# How to construct this n × n matrix using “diag” function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For this question[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvUOi.jpg)

I know something the usage about “diag” function, when n increases, does the matrix looks like a diagonal matrix that other pivots fill with zeros? Does this matrix can be constructed by simply calling the "diag" function?

Comment: This can be done by creating three matrices using diag, one for the diagonal, superdiagonal and subdiagonal then summing the three together.

Comment: So the required matrix should be three 100-row matrix summed up?